# Getting data from different rows but for same column name

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
CUS_ID  CUS_NAME    CUS_CNTRY
    C1  Ajay    India
    C2  Anthony India
    C3  Scott   Australia
    C4  David   UK
    C5  Lisa    India
    C6  Mark    Australia
    C7  Mary    Australia
    C8  Walter  UK
```

---

```
 BRCH_ID    BRCH_NAME   BRCH_STATE
    B1      JP NAGAR    KARNATAKA
    B2      JAYANAGAR   KARNATAKA
    B3      DISPUR      ASSAM
    B4      CUTTACK     ORISSA
    B5      CHANDIGARH  PUNJAB
```

---

```
BRCH_ID CUS_ID  RLTSHP_START_DATE   RLTSHP_END_DATE
B1         C1     1/1/2011             23/12/2011
B1         C4     24/12/2011           4/4/2012
B1         C2     21/12/2011           1/1/2012
B2         C7     2/1/2012             4/4/2012
B3         C4     5/4/2012             31/12/2999
B3         C3     5/7/2010             8/8/2011
B4         C5     9/8/2011             9/4/2012
B4         C6     6/4/2012             31/12/2999
B2         C8     7/1/2009             8/4/2012
B5         C1     24/12/20             31/12/2999
B5         C8     9/4/2012             31/12/2999
```

I want to find out the customers that got transferred from one branch to another in the month of April 2012. Also display the branch from where the customer is transferred and to which branch.

I tried using `case` statement but was not successfull.Now i have this query

```
select b.cus_id, b.brch_id, b1.brch_id
from brch_cus b inner join brch_cus b1 on
b.brch_id=b1.brch_id
where 
b.rltshp_start_date=DATEADD(day, 1,b1.rltshp_end_date)
```

**Expected result**

```
Cus_id     moved_from_branch     moved_to_branch
  C4            B1                   B3
  C8            B2                   B5
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e3a2/12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
;with started as (
    select *
    from  brch_cus
    where rltshp_start_date >= '20120401' and rltshp_start_date < '20120501'
),
ended as (
    select * 
    from  brch_cus
    where rltshp_end_date >= '20120401' and rltshp_end_date < '20120501'
)
select c.cus_id, b_from.brch_id as moved_from_branch, b_to.brch_id as moved_to_branch 
from started s 
inner join ended e on s.cus_id = e.cus_id and s.brch_id <> e.brch_id 
and s.rltshp_start_date = dateadd(day, 1, e.rltshp_end_date)
inner join cus c on s.cus_id = c.cus_id
inner join brch b_from on e.brch_id = b_from.brch_id
inner join brch b_to on s.brch_id = b_to.brch_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer..

```
select a.*, b.*
from 
(select cus_id, brch_id as moved_from_branch
from brch_cus
where rltshp_end_date between '2012-04-01' and '2012-04-30')a
inner join
(select cus_id, brch_id as moved_to_branch
from brch_cus
where rltshp_start_date between '2012-04-01' and '2012-04-30')b
on a.cus_id=b.cus_id;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c4a9/12)

Comment: This would raise a date conversion error as there are only 30 days in April... :p